# Show Files in a ListBox Delphi

Tags: file, delphi, combobox, listbox, mp3

Im trying to create an mp3 player that later I may used as base to create a karaoke the only problem so far is that I want to show the *.mp3 files of a directory that the users select on a ListBox without having to add then manually 1 by 1 and that it only shows the song name not the current path. I have find some ways like using large functions or instead of a ListBox using a ComboBox but it isn't a easier way or transfer the files from the ComboBox to the Listbox?

Comment: Recommended reading: [**Welcome to SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also [**Help Center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) especially about asking questions.

Comment: Your question is unclear and too broad, but having said that, you can use `SelectDirectory()` to let the user select a directory, `FindFirst, FindNext and FindClose` to search the directory for all `.mp3` files to be listed. These functions are covered in the Delphi Help. If you get stuck on details, you are welcome to ask specific questions, showing your attempts (code) sofar and clearly stating your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it will add file name to `ListBox` and save its path to `TStringList` with same `Index` so you can use get both everywhere in your code

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  FilePath: TStringList;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure FindFiles(FilesList: TStrings; FilesPath: TStrings;
  StartDir, FileMask: string);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
  DirList: TStringList;
  IsFound: Boolean;
  i: integer;
begin
  if StartDir[length(StartDir)] <> '\' then
    StartDir := StartDir + '\';

  IsFound := FindFirst(StartDir + FileMask, faAnyFile - faDirectory, SR) = 0;
  while IsFound do
  begin
    FilesPath.Add(StartDir + SR.Name);
    FilesList.Add(SR.Name);
    IsFound := FindNext(SR) = 0;
  end;
  FindClose(SR);

  DirList := TStringList.Create;
  IsFound := FindFirst(StartDir + '*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0;
  while IsFound do
  begin
    if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0) and (SR.Name[1] <> '.') then
      DirList.Add(StartDir + SR.Name);
    IsFound := FindNext(SR) = 0;
  end;
  FindClose(SR);

  for i := 0 to DirList.Count - 1 do
    FindFiles(FilesList, FilePath, DirList[i], FileMask);

  DirList.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  FilePath.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FilePath := TStringList.Create;
  FindFiles(sListBox1.Items, FilePath, EditStartDir.Text, '*.mp3');
  {FilePath is where full file path saved, EditStartDir is where to search}
end;

procedure TForm1.sListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
If sListBox1.ItemIndex > -1 then
  sEdit2.Text := FilePath.Strings[sListBox1.ItemIndex];
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in listing all the files from specific folder without their icons then you might want to use `FileListBox` component from Win 3.1 tab.

You can easily define contents from which directory are shown in it by setting the `Directory` property. Note this property is not exposed to Object inspector to be used at design time but it is perfectly accessible at runtime.

The mentioned component also allows defining filters and even file attributes to show only files that you desire.

The only limitation of mentioned component is that it won't allow you to show files from subfolders which is something a lot of end users would probably like.

For that you would have to search for the files on your own and add them to your desired component one by one.

---

If you want to only display the filename instead of the whole file path you can use `ExtractFileName` procedure but keep in mind that you will still have to somehow keep the full path somewhere so that you know which file to open when certain file is selected on your desired component.

---

There are also some components available which mimic the file browsing behavior similar to `Windows Explorer` like TShellTreeView or TShellListView that shipped with older versions of Delphi.

And quick search on Google shows that there are even more similar components available.